# Remove commas present inside a string in csv

Tags: java, csv, sed

A csv file whose format is

```
name age comments

John 12  Hello World,Example

Jack 14  Hello,World
```

How to replace commas present in comment section with |(pipeline) symbol.

Commas can be present in name, age, and comments too. How to handle it dynamically within a text??

Comment: What is the delimiter character?

Comment: You want to remove the commas from a comma-separated value file?

Comment: Are you looking for a Java solution, or a sed one? They tend to be quite different.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't appear to be using commas as the field separator, it's as simple as

```
sed 's/,/|/g' file
```

To replace only in comments field:

```
while read name age comments; do echo "$name $age ${comments//,/|}"; done < file
```

Comment: This will replace all occurence of ','.I think he needs ',' to be removed only from "comments" section.

Answer (score 0):

```
# any separator char but `/\.&[]` (or need to change the sed action), here `;`
Separator=";"

sed -e ":a
s/\(${Separator}[^${Separator}]*\),\([^${Separator}]*\)$/\1|\2/
ta" YourFile
```

Posix version so `--posix` on GNU sed